# Save/Print a multi-line editbox in MATLAB GUIDE

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I have a multi-line editbox with some messages like this

```
[0] Message 1
[0] Message 2
[0] Message 3
[0] Message 4
```

How can I save this in a  *.txt file?

If I want to print it, I have to print the .txt file or there is a way to print exactly what I have in my editbox?

Answer (score 1):

You can get what is in your edit box with:

```
data = get(handles.edit, 'String');
```

and then save it in a text file with:

```
save('myfile.txt', 'data', '-ASCII')
```

Comment: I get this Warning: « Attempt to write an unsupported data type to an ASCII file. Variable 'data' not written to file.» The file is created but is empty.

Comment: If you use `double(data)`, you will display the ASCII code of your string. You should find values from 65 (A) to 122 (z). If you find other atypical values, your problem may come from that.